# D3 dot plot with horizontal rows of dots like Federal Reserve's prediction plot, HOWTO

Tags: d3.js, plot

So the USA central Bank, the Federal Reserve (Fed), has a committee (FOMC) which publishes closely watched forecasts in the form of a "dot plot".  The graph shows where the committee members expect US Dollar interest rates to be at the end of each year.

I would like a library to plot similar for web output, I'm imagining D3 could do it perhaps.  The curious feature about the Fed's dot plot is the horizontal rows of dots.

Here is an example

[image]

and here is some Json data to play with

```
[
{"Label":"2016","Data":[0.625,0.625,0.625,0.625,0.625,0.625,0.625,0.625,0.625,0.625,0.625,0.625,0.625,0.625,0.625,0.625,0.625]},
{"Label":"2017","Data":[0.875,0.875,1.125,1.125,1.125,1.125,1.375,1.375,1.375,1.375,1.375,1.375,1.625,1.625,1.625,1.75,2.125]},
{"Label":"2018","Data":[0.875,1.625,1.875,1.875,1.875,1.875,1.875,2.125,2.125,2.125,2.375,2.375,2.625,2.625,3,3.25,3.375]},
{"Label":"2019","Data":[0.875,2.125,2.375,2.375,2.625,2.625,2.625,2.875,2.875,3,3,3.125,3.125,3.25,3.25,3.625,3.875]},
{"Label":"Longer run","Data":[2.5,2.75,2.75,2.75,2.75,2.75,2.75,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3.5,3.75]}
]
```

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/asielen/92929960988a8935d907e39e60ea8417 - Look at the beeswarm plot. The code van be found here: https://gist.github.com/asielen/92929960988a8935d907e39e60ea8417

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot is a variation of [violin plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin_plot). Asielen has an exmple on how to use d3.js to render this kind of plots:
http://bl.ocks.org/asielen/92929960988a8935d907e39e60ea8417

Click on the beeswarm button to see a similar plot.

The code is located on https://gist.github.com/asielen/92929960988a8935d907e39e60ea8417.